# Code simplification using Func type instead of Action in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, asynchronous, refactoring

is it possible to refactor this code by using Func type instead of Action?
what I'd like is to get rid of the extra Class (CalcParams) used to return the value with the Action callback.

Edit:
*Note:The download method or Func should be public;

all your help will be very appreciated.

```
public class CalcParams
{
    public int CallID;
    public int Result;
    public Action<int, int> CallbackDone;
    public CalcParams(int callid, Action<int, int> callback)
    {
        CallID = callid;
        CallbackDone = callback;
    }
}
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    int rand;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rand = 0;
    }
    public void DownloadDataInBackground(CalcParams calcparams)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.google.com/search?q={0}", calcparams.CallID));
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            CalcParams localparams = (CalcParams)e.UserState;
            localparams.CallbackDone(localparams.CallID, e.Result.Length);
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri, calcparams);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int callid = rand++;
        Debug.WriteLine("Executing CallID #{0}", callid);
        DownloadDataInBackground(new CalcParams(callid, (c, r) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("The result for the callid {0} is {1}", c, r);
        }));
        callid = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my first approach I'd like to know another easier or cleaner way to do it.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    int rand;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rand = 0;
    }

    public Func<Action<int, int>, Action<int>> DownloadDataInBackground = (callback) =>
    {
        return (c) =>
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.google.com/search?q={0}", c));
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e2) =>
            {
                callback(c, e2.Result.Length);
            };
            client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        };
    };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int callid = rand++;
        Debug.WriteLine("Executing CallID #{0}", callid);
        DownloadDataInBackground((c3, r3) =>Debug.WriteLine("The result for the callid {0} is {1}", c3, r3))(callid);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No it wont. A callback is just that, a method that has some parameters. What is the function of a return value in a callback (Func is just an action with a return value). In your typical case, you it's reasonable not to work with your params class and just pass in the required arguments directly.

```
DownloadDataInBackground(int callId, Action<int, int> callback);
```

Wrapping up parameters in a class can keep your design maintainable. It's up to you to decide when to use a class and when to use parameters.

Apart from that, you can just capture calcparams in DownloadDataInBackground rather then having to use the userstate for that, example:

Comment: please check my answer below, I wonder if thats better or worst approach than the original question, I have added a note in the original question about to keep the Func public because it should be executed from another class, I think it could be easier just to do it the way you propose, but, I what to use Func to not to have a dependency on the download class, im using MEF in my project. and for other reasons.
regards.

Answer (score 1):

Having to add an additional class and/or using `userState` can be avoided quite elegantly with the use of captures.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    Random rand;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rand = new Random();
    }

    public void DownloadDataInBackground(int callId, Action<int> returnResult)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + callId.ToString());
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            // Do something else with result ?
            returnResult(e.Result.Length);
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int callid=rand.Next();
        Debug.WriteLine("Executing CallID #{0}", callid);
        DownloadDataInBackground(callid, r =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("The result for the callid {0} is {1}", callid, r);
        }));
    }
}
```

Note that now only an `Action<int>` is needed, the `callid` in the click event is "captured" to be used in the returnResult callback.

Comment: thank you, in this case it works, but if the callid change before the download is completed it will display another value.the capture could work in DownloadDataInBackground to use it when the download is completed, but button1_Click is not really capturing it.

Comment: @montelof: I think your understanding of how captures work in C# is a little faulty.  Each execution of `button_Click` will get its own storage for the `callid`.  Internaly `callid` actually becomes a member of a class an instance of which is attached to the delegate created by the Lambda.  A new instance is created each time `button1_Click` is called, hence each carries its on "local" value for `callid`.  So your concerns that mutliple calls will overwrite values for outstanding requests is unfounded.

Comment: thank you, but I im trying to explain is precisely that, if I change the value of callid after calling the lambda, it will print another value.if you try the code, add callid=0 at the last line  of button1_Click, the debug.writeline will print 0. the same apply if callid were a global variable within the class. the print Action will get the wrong value.To avoid that is why im returning the callid by the callback. DownloadDataInBackground is indeed capturing the callid used inside the completed event to execute the callback.

Comment: please check the change in the code, I have removed the random number to demonstrate the issue, If you use try to print the variable callid instead of the one returned by the callback, it will print 0. if you execute the code as it is, it will print the correct value, either way my original question was if I could simplify the code using a Func and I have been told is not possible.
thanks.

Comment: @montelof: Yes if you were to modify the variable during the same execution of button_click as you are then that would be a problem.  Do you have such sequential coupling in your real code?  If so then the problem you seem be describing isn't one of `Func` over `Action` more synchronous over asynchronous coding.  If you have signficant sequentially ordered work to do working with Async APIs can be painfull.  Have a look at this series of articles: http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/category/13068.aspx

Comment: you know, at the beginning of my project I was trying to minimize parametrization of everything using captured variables, but after some stress testing I find out some variables were overwritten by the following call, it was very hard to keep track whats captured and whats not, so i decided to use parameters for almost everything.

those articles seems very interesting, I think ill be using AsyncOperation in future projects, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your given comments, i would suggest you to use TPL rather than your own callbacks, this makes life much easier :) (Right now you dont have any exception handling). In the ParallelExtensionsExtra's project as well as .NET 4.5 you'll find another webclient called DownloadStringTask which returns a task. Assuming you are not using that, you can easily replicate it. Check the following code:

```
    public Task<string> DownloadDataInBackground(int id)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> resultTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(id);

        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        Uri uri = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.google.com/search?q={0}", id));
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                resultTaskCompletionSource.SetException(e.Error);
            else if (e.Cancelled)
                resultTaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled();
            else
                resultTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(e.Result);

        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);

        return resultTaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int callid = rand++;
        Debug.WriteLine("Executing CallID #{0}", callid);

        DownloadDataInBackground(callid).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Download for {0} completed with a length of {1}", task.AsyncState, task.Result.Length);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thank you, this is perfect, but I'd like to put that inside a Func, this is becuase I have a viewmodel from where Ill pass the Func as property to another class that has nothing to do with the download one. they are decoupled, Im using MEF, I know this was not part of the initial description, but Ill stick with the part were i stated I'd like to use a Func.